# Forming SQL DB Connection string in arm template outputs using conditional statements

Tags: json, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am creating an ARM template that creates databases(array) on an Azure SQL server and I am trying to output the ADO.NET connection strings and save them in the Key vault. I have 3 connection strings (SQL authentication, AD password Authentication and AD integrated authentication). I am getting the outputs by giving them individually like below:

```
"outputs": {
        "SQLAuthConnectionString": {
            "type": "object",
            "value": {
                "type": "string",
                "value": "[concat('Server=tcp:',reference(parameters('serverName')).fullyQualifiedDomainName,',1433;Initial Catalog=',parameters('dbnameName'),';Persist Security Info=False;User ID=',reference(parameters('serverName')).administratorLogin,';Password=',reference(parameters('serverName')).administratorLoginPassword,';MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;')]"
            }
        },
        "ADPasswordConnectionString": {
            "type": "object",
            "value": {
                "type": "string",
                "value": "[concat('Server=tcp:',reference(parameters('serverName')).fullyQualifiedDomainName,',1433;Initial Catalog=',parameters('dbnameName'),';Persist Security Info=False;User ID=',reference(parameters('serverName')).administratorLogin,';Password=',reference(parameters('serverName')).administratorLoginPassword,';MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication="Active Directory Password"]"
            }
        },
        "ADIntegratedConnectionString": {
            "type": "object",
            "value": {
                "type": "string",
                "value": "[concat('Server=tcp:',parameters('serverName').fullyQualifiedDomainName,,,1433;Initial Catalog=',parameters('databaseName'),';Persist Security Info=False;User ID=',reference(parameters('serverName'))]"
```

However checking to see if we can add conditions in outputs (using a parameter ex: `parameter('authentication_method')` or any other way). Any inputs appreciated as this is my first arm template.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [Azure Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/outputs?tabs=azure-powershell#conditional-output), you can use conditions in the output block of a ARM template when you've [conditionally deployed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/conditional-resource-deployment) a resource.

You can refer [this](https://github.com/bmoore-msft/AzureRM-Samples/blob/master/conditional-output/azuredeploy.json) document, for simple example of conditional output.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that putting a secret into an output, will make that secret available to anyone with READ access over the scope (e.g. resourceGroup, subscription)